# ClassNotFoundException in RestEasy simple configuration

Tags: java, rest, jboss, resteasy

I am using resteasy and have the following configuration in my web.xml. It keeps throwing

`[[/EJBWebClient]]` Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class

```
org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.test.PersonRestController


context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.resources</param-name>
    <param-value>com.test.PersonRestController</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

What could be the problem here? Im deploying it in jboss 4.0.5...Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you packaged your class file for com.test.PersonRestController with your archive (ear or war)?

The classfiles should be stored under

```
WEB-INF/classes
```

Your file should be saved as follows

```
WEB-INF/classes/com/test/PersonRestController.class
```